# error NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Drawing.Skia.Trial. No packages exist with this id in source(s)

Tags: c#, nuget, telerik, reporting, skia

se agrego la definicion con sus credenciales

esto funcionaba correctamente pero recientemente ya no puede obtener las dependencias

```
Local resources cleared.
Determining projects to restore...
D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Domain\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Domain.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Drawing.Skia.Trial. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\library-packs, nuget.org, Paltarumi, telerikNugetV3 \[D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.sln\]
D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Apis\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Apis.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Drawing.Skia.Trial. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\library-packs, nuget.org, Paltarumi, telerikNugetV3 \[D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.sln\]
D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Apis\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Apis.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Reporting.JsonSerialization.Trial. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\library-packs, nuget.org, Paltarumi, telerikNugetV3 \[D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.sln\]
D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Domain\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Domain.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Reporting.JsonSerialization.Trial. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\library-packs, nuget.org, Paltarumi, telerikNugetV3 \[D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.sln\]
D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Apis\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Apis.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Reporting.WebServiceDataSource.Trial. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\library-packs, nuget.org, Paltarumi, telerikNugetV3 \[D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.sln\]
D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Domain\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Domain.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Reporting.WebServiceDataSource.Trial. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\library-packs, nuget.org, Paltarumi, telerikNugetV3 \[D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.sln\]
Failed to restore D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Domain\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Domain.csproj (in 2.56 min).
Failed to restore D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Apis\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Apis.csproj (in 2.56 min).
Restored D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Common\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Common.csproj (in 3 ms).
Restored D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Client\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Client.csproj (in 4 ms).
D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Drawing.Skia.Trial. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\library-packs, nuget.org, Paltarumi, telerikNugetV3 \[D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.sln\]
D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Reporting.JsonSerialization.Trial. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\library-packs, nuget.org, Paltarumi, telerikNugetV3 \[D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.sln\]
D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Reporting.WebServiceDataSource.Trial. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\library-packs, nuget.org, Paltarumi, telerikNugetV3 \[D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.sln\]
D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application.Abstractions\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application.Abstractions.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Drawing.Skia.Trial. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\library-packs, nuget.org, Paltarumi, telerikNugetV3 \[D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.sln\]
D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application.Abstractions\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application.Abstractions.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Reporting.JsonSerialization.Trial. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\library-packs, nuget.org, Paltarumi, telerikNugetV3 \[D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.sln\]
D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application.Abstractions\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application.Abstractions.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Telerik.Reporting.WebServiceDataSource.Trial. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\library-packs, nuget.org, Paltarumi, telerikNugetV3 \[D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.sln\]
Failed to restore D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application.csproj (in 12 ms).
Failed to restore D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application.Abstractions\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Application.Abstractions.csproj (in 12 ms).
Restored D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Repository\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Repository.csproj (in 18 ms).
Restored D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Repository.Abstractions\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Repository.Abstractions.csproj (in 12 ms).
Restored D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.MetalClient\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.MetalClient.csproj (in 2 ms).
Restored D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Entity\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Entity.csproj (in 6 ms).
Restored D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.EmailClient\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.EmailClient.csproj (in 1 ms).
Restored D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Dto\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Dto.csproj (in 0.9 ms).
Restored D:\\a\\1\\s\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Test\\Paltarumi.Acopio.Reporting.Test.csproj (in 31.15 sec).
##\[error\]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

algo que note fue que en le proyecto tampoco trae las dependecias de telerik, pense que era por permisos pero el usuario si tiene permisos.

probe con una rama anterior pensando que algun cambio podria haber sido la causa, pero es asi, talvez un problema de telerik en la actualidad pero ya pasaron 2 dias y no creo, tampoco he visto otros desarrolladores anunciando el error.

Comment: Más personas pueden responder si escribes la pregunta en inglés. 
El sitio no lo tradujo.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).